# Compiler option containing doublequotes and space breaks compilation

Tags: cmake

I need to add a compiler option that contains doublequotes and space to a target in my project. I use `target_compile_options` to add an option.

When I add the option as I would do it on a command line CMake escapes `"` with `\` and adds extra `"` (I assume the second is because of whitespace), thus breaking the compilation.

CMakeLists.txt command:

`target_compile_options(myTarget -Woption="PARAM VALUE" -otherOption)`

Output:

`compiler.exe "-Woption=\"PARAM VALUE\"" -otherOption -o myTarget.o -c myTarget.ext`

Desired output:

`compiler.exe -Woption="PARAM VALUE" -otherOption -o myTarget.o -c myTarget.ext`

I assume I have two problems. One is escaping doublequotes and the second one is escaping whitespace.

### Question

Is it possible to add an option containing doublequotes and whitespace to compiler options? If so can somebody point me to a right direction on how to do it?

#### Notes

I use a cross compiler thus I made the example generic but in case it plays a role this is how the target is compiled:

`set(CMAKE_${lang}_COMPILE_OBJECT "<CMAKE_${lang}_COMPILER> <FLAGS> <INCLUDES> -o <OBJECT> -c <SOURCE>")`

cmake version 3.12

Build platform: Windows

Comment: Aren't the quotes should wrap the **whole** option's definition: "-Woption=PARAM VALUE".

Comment: @Tsyvarev, I tried it but that ended up in `compiler.exe "-Woption=PARAM VALUE" -otherOption -o myTarget.o -c myTarget.ext` and the compiler chokes on it. It really needs `-Woption="PARAM VALUE"`. I assume it parses the command, looks for `-Woption` and passes down `"everything that is in quotes"`.

Comment: Ok, I didn't notice that you are on Windows, where each program implements parsing parameters as it wants. CMake doesn't differentiate programs - on a single platform it uses the same convention about escaping special characters in parameters. And I fear that eliminating of generated wrapping quotes would be hard.

Comment: @MarekKlein I suspect you've played enough with escaping. It almost seems that you need the opposite of [`separate_arguments`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/separate_arguments.html). Maybe you can follow that on the *reverse* (e.g. in github)?